# Can a control blindly proxy another URL, including PostBack?

Tags: asp.net, controls

It is possible to have a control that would proxy requests to another domain/Web site, including postback?

In this control, you would specify the URL you wanted to execute, and whenever the control executed, it would make a GET request to this other URL, and render the HTML return.  (This part is not hard.)

However, when the page is posting back, it would make a POST request, with all of its postback variables intact, to this other page.

I'm really looking for a blind proxy.  Some control that will take the incoming request and throw it another URL, and render the results. The other page would really have no idea it wasn't interacting with a human.

I want to think I could develop this, but I can't be the first person who wants to do it, so there has to be some reason why Google isn't revealing the solution to me.  I suspect I'm going to run into the same Big Problem that anyone else with this idea has run into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this end, this never had much of a chance of working.  I experimented with it for a while, but Postback requires intimate knowledge of the control tree, and there's no way that you're going to be able to apply a postback from the calling page to the other page and have it overlay correctly because the control trees between the two pages are totally different.

Now, if you wanted to write the backend app as a more traditional Web app (even something not in ASP.Net), it might work.  During postback, you could iterate the Request.Form values and send them back, and just have your backend app prepared to accept those incoming values and deal with them, but this wouldn't be a traditional postback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the value of this is; which is probably why you haven't found a solution yet.

However, it seems to me that there are two possible solutions.

1. When the page is rendered have the control modify the form action to point elsewhere; or,
2. on post back, have the control execute a web request to the alternate URL with the post variables and decide what to do with the results at that time.

Comment: I played around with this, and it's just not workable.  The problem is that Postback just doesn't work -- when you post items, the field names are different on the calling page than they would be on the endpoint page, etc.

Comment: @Deane: If you are using .Net 4 you can use the ClientIdMode property to force .Net to render the controls using the ID you supply instead of adding all the normal container names to it.  This works on a control, page, or site level.

Comment: True, but the control trees would be different. The bottom line is that postback on the calling page which contains the proxy control is not going to be the same as postback on the receiving page.  So, pushing postback from one to the other will not give me the results I want.